# HTML table to PDF not working properly

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, angularjs

I am trying to print an HTML table to PDF but I don't get the result I expect. The table is printed in PDF page but its not in proper result. The table is not fixing the width of the PDF page.

I have show screenshot below. The table has more columns and rows.
I am using AngularJS and HTML.
My code is shown below.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IlcL4.png)

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ar">
<head>
<meta>
<script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="2.1.4"       src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.22/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>  
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" media="all" />    
</head>
<body>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<div class="container">
    <br/>
        <button ng-click="exportToExcel('#customers')">XLS</button>
        <button ng-click="exportToPdf()">PDF</button>
        <button >PRINT</button> <br/>
    <br/>
    <table border="1" id="customers" class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
        <tr>
             <th style="width: 125px;">Product Id </th>
             <th>Product Details</th>
             <th>Product Details</th>
             <th>Inventory Update</th>
             <th>Summary</th>
             <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="item in items">
            <td>
                {{productitem.esriproductid}}
            </td>

            <td>
                <div><span class="GridSubTitle">Product Name : </span>{{productitem.productname}}</div>
                <div><span class="GridSubTitle">Product Supplier : </span>{{productitem.productsuppliername}}</div>
                <div><span class="GridSubTitle">Product Type : </span>{{productitem.producttypename}}</div>
                <div><span class="GridSubTitle">Total Quantity : </span>{{productitem.totalquantity}}</div>
                <div><span class="GridSubTitle">Product Price (OMR) : </span>{{productitem.productpriceinOMR}}</div>
                <div ng-if="productitem.datevalidityforprice < FromDate"><span class="GridSubTitle">Date Validity for Price : </span><span class="expirylicense">{{productitem.datevalidityforprice | date:"dd-MMM-yyyy"}}</span></div>
                <div ng-if="productitem.datevalidityforprice >= FromDate"><span class="GridSubTitle">Date Validity for Price : </span>{{productitem.datevalidityforprice | date:"dd-MMM-yyyy"}}</div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div><span class="GridSubTitle">Utilized : </span>{{productitem.ProductUtilization}}</div>
                <div><span class="GridSubTitle">Balance : </span>{{productitem.ProductBalance}}</div>
                <div><span class="GridSubTitle">Total Cost (OMR) : </span>{{productitem.TotalProductCostOMR}}</div>
                <div><span class="GridSubTitle">Usage Type : </span>{{productitem.usagetypename}}</div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div><span class="GridSubTitle">Total Utilized Cost(OMR) : </span>{{productitem.TotalUtilizationProductCostOMR}}</div>
                <div><span class="GridSubTitle">Quantity Utilization Trigger : </span>{{productitem.quantityutilizationtrigger}}</div>
                <div><span class="GridSubTitle">Version : </span>{{productitem.version}}</div>
                <div></div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="action" ng-if="productitem.datevalidityforprice > FromDate">
                    <a href="/LicenseManagement/AddLicense?productid={{productitem.productid}}" title="Edit"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i></a>
                    <a ng-click="deleteproduct(productitem)" title="Delete"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a>
                </div>
                <div>&nbsp;</div>
                <div>&nbsp;</div>
                <div ng-if="productitem.datevalidityforprice > FromDate">
                    <a  ng-click="activeproduct(productitem)" title="Active"><img ng-if="productitem.isactive==1" src="~/Content/img/active.png" /></a>
                    <a ng-click="inactiveproduct(productitem)" title="Deactive"><img ng-if="productitem.isactive==0" src="~/Content/img/inactive.png" /></a>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope,$http,$timeout, Excel) {
       $http.get("cate.json").then(function (response) {$scope.items = response.data;});
        $scope.exportData = function () {
            $('#customers').tableExport({ type: 'json', escape: 'false' });
        };

        $scope.exportToExcel=function(tableId){ // ex: '#my-table'
        var exportHref=Excel.tableToExcel(tableId,'WireWorkbenchDataExport');
        $timeout(function(){location.href=exportHref;},100); // trigger download
    }

         $scope.exportToPdf = function(){
    html2canvas(document.getElementById('customers'), {
        onrendered: function (canvas) {
            var data = canvas.toDataURL();
            var docDefinition = {
                content: [{
                    image: data,
                    width: 110,

                }]
            };
            pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).download("example.pdf");
             pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).download("test.pdf");
        }
    });
 }
    });
    app.factory('Excel',function($window){
    var uri='data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,',
        template='<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>',
        base64=function(s){return $window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s)));},
        format=function(s,c){return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g,function(m,p){return c[p];})};
    return {
        tableToExcel:function(tableId,worksheetName){
            var table=$(tableId),
                ctx={worksheet:worksheetName,table:table.html()},
                href=uri+base64(format(template,ctx));
            return href;
        }
    };
 })
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Did you try to create and print a smaller version of the table first? Most of the time, someone may have extra <td> somewhere.Or your if must be in braces. Make an effort to show a smaller table in your questions. Spend the time to do if you expect others to do the same, read it, and help you.

Comment: For smaller version of table is working.

Comment: From the small example, start including your data row by row and see which one will break it.